# Logic programming help

Tags: php, logic

A = if **infos** !empty and **inputs** empty
 *- do remove;*

B = if **infos** empty and **inputs** !empty 
 *- do add;*

C = if **infos** !empty and **inputs** !equal to infos
*- do add;*

We can have like:

```
if B //it's the most common operation, so at the beginning.
{
  //add 
}
else
{
 //remove
}
elseif(c) 
{
 //the same add
}
```

I believe this can be better thinking. Can I have your help?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just something. It could be blabla. In this case, I'm trying to compare values from a database to those "inputed" by the user. So info will represent those coming from the database.

Comment: This question does not seem relevant to [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming). If you actually want to do logic programming in PHP, then you can use a library like [reasoned-PHP](https://github.com/igorw/reasoned-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (infos != inputs) {
    if (empty(inputs)) {
        // remove
    } else {
        // add
    }
}
```

Remember, the outermost condition checks that both values are never empty (never the same, actually). E.g.,

> A = if **infos** !empty and **inputs** empty - *do remove;*

If **inputs** is empty **infos** can *not* be empty. Therefore, remove.

> B = if **infos** empty and **inputs** !empty - *do add;*
>   C = if **infos** !empty and **inputs** !equal to infos - *do add*;

Different and **inputs** not empty => it doesn't mather whether **info** is empty => add.

Comment: I believe this covers all the possibilities. 
If they are equal, do nothing.
If they are different, and input is empty - do remove.
If they are different, and input isn't empty - do add.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (B || C) 
{
  //add 
}
else
{
 //remove
}
```

Comment: The only think here, is that, the C condition plus the B condition could because quite big. :s So, I better store those comparisons into a variable, and use those variables instead. What do you think?

Comment: This would also remove when both are empty.

Comment: @Gumbo: Please clarify - both what - infos or inputs ?

Comment: ow... infos and inputs ? if both infos and inputs are empty this will not properly work?

Comment: @MEM if you want to use the B and C conditions later on, store them in a variable, if you only want to use them once, put them directly in the condition. be sure to use (B) || (C), so nested conditions, if any, doesn't get evaluated in a way you don't want.

Comment: @MEM: Yes, I meant *infos* and *inputs*. But I have to admit that I was wrong with my objection (overlooked the “!” in “!equal”). But this will fail if `!empty($infos)` but `$inputs == $infos`. Because in that case this will run the *remove* branch although the second condition `empty($inputs)` is not fulfilled.

Comment: Sorry Gumbo: (kidda slow today) - when you mention "this" do you mean the Dezigo answer, our your objection? Thanks.

Comment: @MEM: “This” refers to Dezigo’s answer.

Comment: @All - So, the else branch (remove) will execute when B or C are not the case.
If !empty infos and input==infos, then the else will run. Hence, the remove will be executed. However, the intend result is to ignore, and do nothing if that's the case, SO, this answers as Gumbo noted, seems not to be appropriate. Yes?

Answer (score 2):

it's `if`, `elseif` (as much `elseif`'s as you want) and finally `else`:

```
if B //it's the most common operation, so at the beginning.
{
  //add 
} elseif(something else) 
{
 //the same add
} elseif(c) 
{
 //the same add
} else
{
 //remove
}
```

Comment: The thing is, that we are repeating the add code, it's exactly the same, so probably having only one "add" will be better?

Comment: I see... we are repeating the code, so either we do like Dezigo suggest, or we grab that repetition and convert that into a method? Or I'm not properly understand it ?

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice he wants to add in both cases.

Comment: I really like your if elseif else representation. :) I will mark as useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You sure can do that. Just order the conditional blocks: `If... Else If... Else`.

Comment: @aularon & Daniel - Ohh! Nice. So we do have if, else if... else if... and the else at the end will be the contrary of the FIRST if condition. precise?

Comment: @mem - No, it will only be executed if none of the other blocks are executed.

Comment: Thanks - So else, doesn't mean the opposite, or the contrary. Just, something different. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !A ) {
  add;
} else {
  remove;
}
```

Short and clear in my opinion.

Comment: @Gumbo you are correct. Dident see this case in the specs so i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the conditions of *B* and *C* with the OR operator:

```
if (empty($infos) && !empty($inputs) || !empty($infos) && $inputs != $infos) {
    // add
} else if (!empty($infos) && empty($inputs)) {
    // remove
}
```

Comment: Can you please comment on your comments, when you refer to both, what are you referring to? 

:D

Comment: I'm with Gumbo. :) I believe this info is helpfull.